# Filtering a part of data in mysql joint table

Tags: mysql, sql, filtering

Here's the initial mysql code I have that shows what I need:

```
    SELECT (
    CASE 
       WHEN (c.`norm_id` = 71) THEN 71
       ELSE c.parent_id
    END) AS parent, 
    SUM(d.number) AS parent_sum,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(c.norm_id)) AS child_cnt
FROM un_catalog AS c
    LEFT JOIN un_data AS d ON (c.norm_id =  d.type2_norm_id)
    LEFT JOIN exp_weblog_titles AS wt USING (entry_id)
WHERE (c.parent_id != '') AND (c.`type_id` = 2) OR (c.norm_id = 71) 
GROUP BY parent
ORDER BY parent ASC;
```

[image: Here's what it shows]

Now I add a filter:

```
 SELECT (
    CASE 
       WHEN (c.`norm_id` = 71) THEN 71
       ELSE c.parent_id
    END) AS parent, 
    SUM(d.number) AS parent_sum,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(c.norm_id)) AS child_cnt
FROM un_catalog AS c
    LEFT JOIN un_data AS d ON (c.norm_id =  d.type2_norm_id)
    LEFT JOIN exp_weblog_titles AS wt USING (entry_id)
WHERE (c.parent_id != '') AND (wt.year = 2014) AND (c.`type_id` = 2) OR (c.norm_id = 71) 
GROUP BY parent
ORDER BY parent ASC;
```

[image: result]

I need to filter data from second table (column 2) while keeping structure (columns 1 and 3) without filtering. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When outer join, don't put outer table conditions in the `WHERE` clause, put then on the `ON` clause. (Otherwise the outer join works as a regular inner join...)

```
 SELECT (
    CASE 
       WHEN (c.`norm_id` = 71) THEN 71
       ELSE c.parent_id
    END) AS parent, 
    SUM(d.number) AS parent_sum,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(c.norm_id)) AS child_cnt
FROM un_catalog AS c
    LEFT JOIN un_data AS d ON (c.norm_id = d.type2_norm_id)
    LEFT JOIN exp_weblog_titles AS wt ON wt.entry_id = XXX.entry_id AND (wt.year = 2014)
WHERE (c.parent_id != '')  AND (c.`type_id` = 2) OR (c.norm_id = 71) 
GROUP BY parent
ORDER BY parent ASC;
```

Note that I didn't know which table entry_id belongs to, so replace XXX above with either c or d! (`USING`...)

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! Never knew we can use filters in "ON". Thank you!